# How to store UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cell

I need to get `indexPath` of cell to delete but my app has auto reload after 2s to check new file so `indexpath` has changed so I don't get it correctly. Now, I want get cell but I don't know how to store cell. This is my codes:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //[_tableView clearsContextBeforeDrawing];
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    }
    cell.tag = indexPath.row;

    if([FileNameArray count] != 0){
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10, 05, 100, 20);//(20, 0, 80, 40);
    UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
    [lbl1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0]];
    [lbl1 setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [lbl1 setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
    lbl1.text = [FileNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell addSubview:lbl1];
    [lbl1 release];
    }
    return cell;

}
```

`removeCell` function:

```
-(void) removeCell:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [_tableView beginUpdates];
      [_tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
   // [_tableView reloadData];
    [_tableView endUpdates];

}
```

Do you have suggestions?

Comment: There are several approaches to determining the `NSIndexPath` for a cell (e.g., `indexPathForCell`, `indexPathForRowAtPoint`, ...). How do you determine that a cell should be deleted and thus invoke your `removeCell` method?

Comment: @bobnoble: i tried use indexPathForCell to get indexpath of first row but not successful. On tableview has only 1 row response from server, i want to delete first row but not get indexpath of it.

Comment: Are you trying to replace the `UITableView` content (i.e., rows) with new data from the server? If so, you should be able to use `[_tableView reloadData]` which will rebuild the table, with no need for you to explicitly delete rows. If this is not what you are trying to accomplish, please provide more detail on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: HI bob, i used [_tableView reloadData], my uitableview has delete 1 row. you can see image at here: http://uploadingit.com/file/view/h82cwjjghsn3mqil/Screen%20Shot%202013-07-08%20at%201.36.48%20PM.png